# How to send photo with Telegram bot API in Java

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I have some API endpoint that contains photo and I want to send it to Telegram bot using my Telegram bot controller using `SendPhoto` class and I tried with the following code

```
SendPhoto sendPhoto = new SendPhoto();
sendPhoto.setChatId(chatId);
sendPhoto.setPhoto("http://localhost:3000/media/photo_97@05-06-2023_00-22-51.jpg");
```

This resulted in error of method setPhoto doesn't support String parameters and only supports InputFile type

So I tried the following

```
SendPhoto sendPhoto = new SendPhoto();
sendPhoto.setChatId(chatId);
sendPhoto.setPhoto(new InputFile("http://localhost:3000/media/photo_97@05-06-2023_00-22-51.jpg"));
```

This gave me this error which I don't understand

```
Error executing org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendPhoto query: [400] Bad Request: wrong HTTP URL specified
```

I also tried to test the endpoint using Postman more than once and it seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that class `InputFile` has a constructor with this signature `public InputFile(InputStream mediaStream, String fileName)` which accepts input stream of the file and the file path as parameters so I tried this and it worked.

```
InputStream stream = new URL(myUrl).openStream();
SendPhoto sendPhoto = new SendPhoto();
sendPhoto.setChatId(chatId);
sendPhoto.setPhoto(new InputFile(stream, myUrl));
```